# multiple input in a single prompt box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a simple web application using javascript.
I want to know that how to add multiple inputs in a single prompt box using javascript.

Comment: I think you will have to create a hidden form and then hide/show and submit it using javascript.

Comment: Try modal dialogs instead of javascript prompts

Answer (score 1):

Go to this website, they have a full code, explanation, and example for you to learn how to achieve what you wanted.

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_form.asp

Summary of what you should do:

1. Create a form, just like usual
2. hide the form using display:none
3. Then create a button
4. Create a JS script, that "onclick" on the
   button, will unhide the form.

as simple as that